The Helmholtz equation for the spherical harmonics with delta functions
In three dimensions, the Green’s function for the Helmholtz equation with a radiating point source
$$
(\nabla^{2}+k_{0}^{2})g(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}')=\delta(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}')
$$
is
$$
g(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}')=g(r)=-\frac{e^{ik_{0}r}}{4\pi r}
$$
where $r=|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}'|$. General radiating separable solutions to the Helmholtz equation in spherical coordinates have an angular dependence given by spherical harmonics, $Y_{n}^{m}(\theta,\phi)$, via:
$$
f_{n}^{m}(r,\theta,\phi)=h_{n}^{(1)}(k_{0}r)Y_{n}^{m}(\theta,\phi)
$$
where $h_{n}^{(1)}(\sigma)$ denotes the order n spherical Hankel function of the first kind. Up to a normalisation constant, the $n=m=0$ case reduces to the Green’s function. My question is what is the correct form of the Helmholtz equation satisfied by $f_{n}^{m}(r,\theta,\phi)$ that includes the appropriate delta function singularity at the origin? I understand that the $n=1$ spherical harmonics correspond to radiating point dipoles but don’t know how to express this in the Helmholtz equation. It may be a case of generalising the following proof for the $n=m=0$ case perhaps by multiplying the equation by a ‘test’ function before integrating.
Consider integrating $(\nabla^{2}+k_{0}^{2})g(r)$ over a sphere of radius $δ≪1$. Given that $\lim_{\delta\to0}\delta^{2}g(\delta)=0$, we need consider only the first term where we employ the divergence theorem:
$$
\int_{r<\delta}\nabla^{2}g(r)dV=\int_{r=\delta}\nabla g(r).\hat{\textbf{r}}dA=\int_{r=\delta}\frac{dg}{dr}dA\sim\int_{r=\delta}\frac{e^{ik_{0}r}}{4\pi r}dA\sim1
$$
as $\delta\to0$. Therefore
$$
\lim_{\delta\to0}\int_{r<\delta}(\nabla^{2}+k_{0}^{2})g(r)=1
$$
With $g(r)$ being a solution to the Helmholtz equation away from the origin, the Helmholtz equation for the Green’s function follows.
Thanks in advance for any help.

I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking for, but ...
Let $\square_m = \nabla^2 + m^2$ and let $G$ be the solution to $\square_m G = \delta$ vanishing at infinity, i.e.
$$G(\mathbf x)=-\frac{e^{im|\mathbf x|}}{4\pi|\mathbf x|}.$$
Then, $\square_m (\nabla G) = \nabla \delta,$ or $\square_m (\mathbf P\cdot \nabla G) = \mathbf P\cdot\nabla \delta,$ for a dipole moment vector $\mathbf P.$
Similarly, for a quadrupole moment $Q^{ab}$ the equation is simply
$\square_m (Q^{ab}\partial_a\partial_b G) = Q^{ab}\partial_a\partial_b\delta.$
